# Google Analytics API - requesting all deviceId for particular UTM-marker

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

is there a way to run API call which lists all users (deviceId of each user) which came through utm_medium=my_utm_medium?

At the moment I see that UTM-markers may only be retrieved through Basic Reports while deviceId is only accessible through Audience Export.

I wonder if there is a way to get both
Thank you in advance